# A question regarding Open, Closed and Isolated systems

Tags: thermodynamics, mass-energy

While revising Chemical Thermodynamics as usual,  I came across a term called *Closed System* - which is defined as a system which exchanges energy with the surroundings and not matter. But, according to Einstein's theory, mass and energy are two sides of the same coin and are inter-convertible. So, doesn't exchanging energy imply exchanging matter? If it is so, why do we need this term called *Closed System*? And couldn't we just define *Open* and *Isolated* systems in terms of either mass or energy instead of both?

Comment: We aren't just changing the mass of an open system but the matter composition. Mass and matter are not equivalent. For the purposes of thermodynamics the matter composition matters but the total mass doesn't since we are not considering the dynamics of the system and its gravitational interactions. An exception is black hole thermodynamics which only depends on mass since the theory doesn't know anything about matter and its internal details.

Comment: @FlatterMann I ask again, please post answers as answers rather than comments.

Comment: @Chemomechanics If you think that qualifies as an answer rather than just a handwave, I am happy to do so.

Answer (score 2):

The essential concept here is that of conservation laws. For matter there are various things that are conserved. In ordinary circumstances, for example, the amount of each chemical element is a conserved quantity. More generally one has conservation of lepton number and baryon number and electric charge and things like that.

When a closed system loses energy its rest mass goes down. When a closed system gains energy its rest mass goes up. This does NOT imply it has gained or lost any matter.

In thermodynamic calculations we track the amount of matter by using either the number of particles $N$ or the number of moles $n$, or some other suitable way of tracking the movement of matter itself.

Answer (score 1):

In thermodynamics we are normally only interested in the energy that mass carries with it in the form of kinetic and potential energy (internal and external), as opposed to the energy equivalent of mass per Einstein. What’s more, energy crossing the boundary not carried by mass is in the form of heat and/ or work. That’s the assumption in the definitions of closed and isolated systems.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

We aren't just changing the mass of an open system but the matter composition. Mass and matter are not equivalent. For the purposes of thermodynamics the matter composition matters but the total mass doesn't since we are not considering the dynamics of the system and its gravitational interactions. An exception is black hole thermodynamics which only depends on mass since the theory doesn't know anything about matter and its internal details.